# I need to extract only particular pattern from a string using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As i need to extract only particular pattern from string:

```
import re

string='/x/eng/wcov/Job148666--rollup_generic/Job148674--ncov_aggregate/Job148678--run_command/Job148678.info:  devN_180107_2035'

line2=re.findall(r'(?:/\w*)' ,string)
print(line2)
```

I'm getting output as below:

```
['/x', '/eng', '/wcov', '/Job148666', '/Job148674', '/Job148678', '/Job148678']
```

But actual output i required is:

```
/x/eng/wcov/Job148666--rollup_generic/Job148674--ncov_aggregate/Job148678--run_command/Job148678.info
```

Comment: When the string always start the same and ends the same, you can use split, which will make your life easier than using regex

Comment: I don't see the difference between the string and the actual required output, besides the extension, can you explain further what you need? Using split you could extract everything between the /'s for example, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `split()` function

```
string='/x/eng/wcov/Job148666--rollup_generic/Job148674--ncov_aggregate/Job148678--run_command/Job148678.info:  devN_180107_2035'

sp=string.split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the string always end with `:`? Then use this

```
str.split(":", 1)[0]
```